# Why is my program crashing when I debug?

Tags: c, crash, structure, scanf

I've started to write a program that reads and stores team info and stores in a structure, reorders and prints results.

First i'm trying to read team names and stores them in a member in a structure, then read team scores and store them in another member.

However, as soon as i debug the file, it crashes. It doesn't even start correctly. I get this error

> Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in PA2.exe: 0xC0000005 Access
>   violation executing location 0xFEFEFEFE.

I've backtracked enough to figure out that it is somewhere in the while loop but can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I am using visual studio 2012 and i get no errors when i build it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct team
{
    char name[20];
    int no_games;
    int points;
    int goals_scored;
    int goals_let;
};


int main(void)
{
    FILE *input2a;
    FILE *input2b;
    int error1;
    int error2;
    int i;
    char team1_name[20];
    char team2_name[20];
    int team1_goals;
    int team2_goals;
    struct team teamlist[20];

    error1 = fopen_s(&input2a, "C:\\Users\\New PC\\Desktop\\input2a.dat", "r");

    i = 0;
    while (i < 20)
    {
        i ++;
        fscanf_s(input2a, "%s", teamlist[i].name);
    }

    error2 = fopen_s(&input2b, "C:\\Users\\New PC\\Desktop\\input2b.dat", "r");

    while (fscanf_s(input2b, "%s %d %s %d", team1_name, &team1_goals, team2_name, &team2_goals) !=EOF)
    {
        if (team1_goals < 0)
        {
            printf("Team %s has negative goals - Invalid entry\n", team1_name);
        }

        else if (team2_goals < 0)
        {
            printf("Team %s has negative goals - Invalid entry\n", team2_name);
        }

        else
        {
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged already? You would see the exact line where it crashs?

Comment: windows doesn't support C

Comment: 1) `i ++;` move to loop end (after `fscanf_s`) 2) `%s` of `fscanf_s` need size parameter. e.g `fscanf_s(input2a, "%s", teamlist[i].name, sizeof teamlist[i].name);`

Comment: I'd wildly guess at one or both of the files being missing/unreadable based on you **ignoring all error cases** like checking the return codes from `fopen_s`

Comment: `while (fscanf_s(input2b, "%s %d %s %d", team1_name, &team1_goals, team2_name, &team2_goals) !=EOF)` should be `while (fscanf_s(input2b, "%s %d %s %d", team1_name, &team1_goals, team2_name, &team2_goals)  == 4)`

Answer (score 5):

From only looking at the while loop: you write to memory out of bounds.

```
struct team teamlist[20];
```

And in the while:

```
i = 0;
while (i < 20)
{
    i ++;
    fscanf_s(input2a, "%s", teamlist[i].name);
}
```

So you enter the while when `i=19` and increase it to `20` which makes it out of the bounds for the array.

Comment: I've updated my code to check for errors and changed it to a for loop to fix the out of bounds error. It prints that both files are loaded correctly then crashes immediately after.

https://gist.github.com/Lemewinks/c9446fe62f75d472e8a9

Comment: @dos584 Please incorporate all suggestions given in the answers as well as the comments.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here (see my comment):

```
i = 0;
while (i < 20)
{
    i ++; // was 19, become 20, but maximal allowed value is 19
    fscanf_s(input2a, "%s", teamlist[i].name);
}
```

The name of this problem is ABW (array bounds write). It means, that your program writes outside array (it happens when `i==19`, so the condition of the loop `i < 20` is satisfied, but right after it you increase it: `i++`). To fix it you need just to swap two lines of the body of this loop:

```
{
    fscanf_s(input2a, "%s", teamlist[i].name);
    i++;
}
```

And much better and simplier it would be to use `for` loop here:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    fscanf_s(input2a, "%s", teamlist[i].name);
```

And the last fix: now there is still possible ABW error. The reason of it is simple: size of `teamlist[i].name` is 20. So, if input file contains long lines, your program will write outside this array. To fix it you can extend `"%s` this way (we have here "19" instead of "20" because last character is `'\0'`):

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    fscanf_s(input2a, "%19s", teamlist[i].name);
```

And one more thing about `fscanf_s()`: this function shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items. So in the second loop it is better to check, that it returns `4`.

**Update:**

If nothing happens, let's open [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable. For example, if you are reading a string, the
>   buffer size for that string is passed as follows:
>
> `char s[10];`
>
> `scanf_s("%9s", s, _countof(s)); // buffer size is 10, width specification is 9`

So in your case in means, that first loop should be corrected this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    fscanf_s(input2a, "%19s", teamlist[i].name, _countof(teamlist[i].name));
```

And you need the same fix for next call of `fscanf_s` in the second loop, because there are two `"%s"`s in that call.

Comment: @dos584, show us content of both input files: "input2a.dat" and "input2b.dat".

Comment: @dos584 You need one more argument for `fscanf_s`. See [@BLUEPIXY's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013879/why-is-my-program-crashing-when-i-debug-structures#comment53851189_33013879)

Comment: file 2a: Arsenal AstonVilla Bournemouth Chelsea CrystalPalace Everton Leicester Liverpool
ManCity ManUtd Newcastle Norwich Southampton Stoke Sunderland Swansea
Tottenham Watford WestBrom WestHam.

Comment: @dos584, I've updated my answer (thanks to Cool Guy!). I expect that now the problem is fixed.